# AppCompat style background propagated to the Image within the ToolBar

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

**Context**

I'm using the newest AppCompat v7 lib (21.0.0) and I have migrated my app from ActionBar to ToolBar

**Problem**

1. Images in the ToolBar automatically receive the same background as the ToolBar

Currently the SearchBox is a custom view set on the action bar (From previous implementation) I plan to switch if to the SearchView and style it accordingly but I'm still very interested in the problem I'm facing right now.

[image: Img background]

2. When long pressing on a menu item in the ToolBar a toast appear with the hint text and the text has the same background than the ToolBar.

[image: Toast background]

How can I avoid this?

Here is my toolbar layout and the style & theme

layout v_toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/MyActionBarStyle"/>
```

values/styles.xml

```
<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/green</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@color/green</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Theme

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- Here we setting appcompat’s actionBarStyle -->
    <!-- <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item> -->

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- ...and here we setting appcompat’s color theming attrs -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/green_dark</item>
</style>
```

<strike>**Workaround 1 for problem 1**</strike>

The workaround for the first problem is to set a transparent background on the ImageView

```
android:background="@color/transparent"
```

This does not solve the toast issue.

**Solution for both problems**

I set a background to the ToolBar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/green"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/MyActionBarStyle"/>
```

And I'm not setting the background on the theme anymore.

```
<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

As pointed by Chris Banes, a style could be created for the toolbar instead of declaring the android:background.

This fixes my problem but then I seem to have another issue with the fact that the popupTheme isn't applied and my ShareActionMenuItem drop down does not have a white background with black text.
See another question here: [AppCompat ToolBar popupTheme not used in the ShareAction MenuItem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26504532/1228221)

Maybe this is a bug in the appcompat library.

Comment: You can try the second workaround. It solves the problem but bring another one if you want Dark ActionBar & Light dropdown

Comment: So I'm gonna need to manage 2 different themes for the real actionbar (when used) and for the toolbar (whenever needed)?

Comment: No you get rid of the old actionbar, you only use ToolBar now

Comment: Would this mean I need to add a toolbar to every activity now (via XML or java)? feels kind of odd

Comment: yes, put it in its own xml layout

Comment: what would you suggest if one wants to use the the background color in the whole application?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You should not be using `theme` like that:

- style = local to the Toolbar
- theme = global to everything inflated in the Toolbar

Workaround 2, as you call it, is kind of the correct way. If you want to extract some values into a style, you can do it as so:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    style="@style/MyDarkToolbar" />
```

Style:

```
<style name="MyDarkToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/green</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Ok I know styles I used them like that previsouly but what you wrote on your blog "app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" "  what do they mean ? I did lots of tests and the workaround 2 is much better and yes as you pointed out using a style would make it even better. Please see also my other question as it is related to the popupTheme.

Comment: Chris, thanks for elucidating the distinction between 'style' and 'theme.' What is the difference between Theme.AppCompat and ThemeOverlay.AppCompat?

Comment: I've tried many things and most of them were kind of the same but this is the only one that has worked for me. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

Never use themes to edit. Because theme defines overall app behavior. U can use two methods for that

**Method:1**

U can directly specify the parameters in appbar.xml as shown below

in appbar.xml

```html
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/green"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme=">style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

**Method:2**

you can use a style as Chris_Banes suggested in above post

in appbar.xml:

```html
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    style="@style/MyDarkToolbar" />
```

in Style:

```html
<style name="MyDarkToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/green</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

**Points To Note**

> With the new Toolbar you can apply a style and a theme. They are
>   different! The style is local to the Toolbar view, for example the
>   background color. The app:theme is instead global to all ui elements
>   inflated in the Toolbar, for example the color of the title and icons.