# AppCompat ToolBar popupTheme not used in the ShareAction MenuItem

Tags: android, styles, themes, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

**Context**

Using the AppCompat v7 21.0.0 / 21.0.2 / 21.0.3

**Problem**

The popupTheme of the ToolBar is not applied to the ShareAction

Style on the toolbar:

```
<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/green</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

The overflow menu item is using the popupTheme properly

[image: Overflow Item]

The ShareAction on the other hand does not receive the popupTheme. After some testing I noticed it received the app:theme of the ToolBar thus being dark.

```
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>
```

[image: ShareAction Menu Item]

In order to get the black text on the ShareAction I tried setting many attributes and by setting "android:textColorPrimary" (on the ToolBar theme) I get what I want BUT then my icons on the ToolBar also takes this color which is weird...

The menu xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cycle="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_share_holo_dark"
        android:title="@string/media_share"
        cycle:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        cycle:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_share_holo_dark"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="br">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menuSortNewest"
                android:title="Sort by newest" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menuSortRating"
                android:title="Sort by rating" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

I would expect both the ShareAction & the overflow to have the popupTheme but it's not the case

**Workaround**

I'll edit this post once I got a workaround

Ref: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=87285&thanks=87285&ts=1419254842

Answer (score 30, accepted):

So, here's what worked for me.
Here's my Toolbar xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_main"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    app:theme="@style/Toolbar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/Toolbar_Popup"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

Notice that I set both theme and popupTheme, and I also override background to be colorPrimary.
Here's the main app theme description with themes for Toolbar:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>

    <item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/actionbar_height</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#607d8b</item>

</style>

<style name="Toolbar" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/dark_blue</item>
</style>

<style name="Toolbar_Popup" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/dark_blue</item>
</style>
```

So, as a result, Share action background is set to the value of background in the main Toolbar theme. And the background of Toolbar itself is overriden.

Comment: Something useful to add would be <item name="android:drawSelectorOnTop">true</item>, for me the selector was  only showing as a border around the words in the list when pressed otherwise

Comment: @Max yah it doesn't. what is the new solution from v7:23.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I was scratching my head for ages trying to solve this.  I found a solution to my problem. Hopefuully this will help others also:

In my toolbar definition I was setting a custom theme like so:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar     
    ...
    app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
    ... />
```

In my styles.xml, my theme was defined as:

```
<style name="ActionBarThemeOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#fff</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#3fff</item>
</style>
```

I wanted white action icons in my toolbar, so I was setting these values to white.  Unfortunately it was also making my ShareActionProvider menu text white (on a white background).

The solution for me was to remove the style setting for `textColorPrimary`.  My toolbar icons were still white but I now had the desired dark text in the popup share provider menu.

```
<style name="ActionBarThemeOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#fff</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#3fff</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This page may helps to solve your problem: http://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2014/10/28/android-changing-the-toolbars-text-color-and-overflow-icon-color/

One difference I noticed in your XML is that you once use the property android:showAsAction="ifRoom" and once cycle:showAsAction="ifRoom".

Comment: Yes the android/cycle is a copy paste mistake. and the website does not talk about this particular problem, it is in fact a bug in the AppCompat lib that will be fixed soon