# How to change color of toolbar options background

Tags: android, xml

I want to change the light background of options in the toolbar as well as the section that appears when trying to copy something. It's really bad right now:

[image]

Here is my styles.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    !-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
     <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
     <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>

  </style>

  <!-- Application theme. -->
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ToolBar" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.NavMenu" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/gray</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.RightMenu" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

As you may have noticed I'm using `NoActionBar` because I'm using a toolbar. It's on my main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<!-- your content layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Toolbar instead of ActionBar so the drawer can slide on top -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:theme="@style/MyTheme.ToolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
    <!-- Real content goes here -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_view_header"
        app:menu="@layout/nav_view_menu"
        app:theme="@style/MyTheme.NavMenu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this in your Toolbar:**

```
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
```

[AppCompat ToolBar popupTheme not used in the ShareAction MenuItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26504532/appcompat-toolbar-popuptheme-not-used-in-the-shareaction-menuitem)

And here is with `AppBarLayout`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarmain"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

**Take a look at this also:**

```
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
```

Comment: Where should I apply the popup theme?

Comment: The popup theme really helped with the user experience, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure are you want to use ActionMode or Toolbar:
To change color of toolbar look at this link

[Change Toolbar color in Appcompat 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554996/change-toolbar-color-in-appcompat-21)

OR to change color of ActionMode look at this link

[How to change ActionMode background color in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769315/how-to-change-actionmode-background-color-in-android)

Comment: I'm using support library.

Comment: OK, can you explain to me why this method doesn't work in your case?