# How to make Toolbar transparent and put an image backwards it?

Tags: android

I want the `ToolBar` to be transparent. I have an Activity that is showing a Toolbar and looks like this:

[image]

I have this on my xml:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

But I can't make my Activity be on top and be visible at the back of my ToolBar...

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Make layout file for `Toolbar` and add `ImageView` in it.

Comment: All my activites extend from this Toolbar, so I don't think that's a solution...

Answer (score 2):

StackOverflow does not allow me to comment because I don't have 50 reputation that why I am commenting in answer box

You can find you answer here:

[How to make the support Toolbar background transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574138/how-to-make-the-support-toolbar-background-transparent)

[How to make Toolbar transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505632/how-to-make-toolbar-transparent)

Comment: wanted to do exactly the same thing.

Comment: So then my problem is that my Activity is moved down for some reason... Why it looks down?=

Answer (score 1):

@RAP's answer seems work. But note that if you set the background to transparent, means that the toolbar is still clickable when user touch on it and doing some actions you don't want. Other alternative to achieve your goal is by setting its visibility to `INVISIBLE`:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

toolbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

// to make it appear again:
toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```