# Android How to make status and toolbar transparent in Nexus

Tags: android, statusbar, android-toolbar

I am trying to make my toolbar and status bar transparent like below Image.

[image]

But I am getting like this

[image]

can anyone help me how to make this transparent.

I tried all links below, but no use

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505632/how-to-make-toolbar-transparent)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27532167/android-transparent-overlay-toolbar)

[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574138/how-to-make-the-support-toolbar-background-transparent)

Here is my code

**MainActivity.java:-**

```
  package aleph.transparent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = this;
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
    //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    // Check if the version of Android is Lollipop or higher
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        // Set paddingTop of toolbar to height of status bar.
        // Fixes statusbar covers toolbar issue
        //toolbar.setPadding(0, getStatusBarHeight(), 0, 0);
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}



public int getStatusBarHeight() {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}}
```

**activity_main.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**appbar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="aleph.transparent.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**toolbar.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

**nav_header_main.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Android Studio"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android.studio@android.com" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**content_main.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/bellow_actionbar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="aleph.transparent.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_pay" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="aleph.transparent">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**style.xml:-**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    <style name="WalletButton">
        <item name="android:textSize">19sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29907616/4494555

Comment: Tried but no use :( .  My device us nexus running with Marshmellow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android transparent status bar and actionbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907615/android-transparent-status-bar-and-actionbar)

Comment: Tried this as well no use

Answer (score 0):

Change background color to transparent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

If above change is not working and taking the default color then change it programmatically :-

```
mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
mToolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
```

Comment: No use if I do transparent, it is giving default background colour blue.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
```

and remove android:theme from here:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
```

But don't make it full transparent, you can use color to have transparency like `#93000000` so it will be like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#93000000"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
```

**Output coming like this:-**

[image]