# how to add a picture on the entire screen without disturbing the statusbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I see it in some applications, how do I add it to my application?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the support Toolbar background transparent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574138/how-to-make-the-support-toolbar-background-transparent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android:label="@string/foo" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

Answer (score 0):

Status bar is always Transparent.

What you want is to see no ToolBar

Apply theme to your application tag in manifest or to your individual activity if you want this :

```
Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar
```

Now you will have your entire screen at your disposal and you can set your image to match_parent and view it in full screen

Answer (score 0):

within the tag specify height and weight as match parent
in the  style sheet  make action not visible
parent="Theme. App Compat. Light. noActionBar"