# Navigation icon toast hint

Tags: android, android-toolbar, navigationitem

Android toolbar menu items show toast hints on long press. The toast message is defined in xml with "title" attribute:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/openRightMenu"
    android:orderInCategory="300"
    android:title="@string/navigation_drawer_right_desc"
    android:icon="@drawable/menu24_2"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />
```

Can i set the same behaviour for the toolbar's navigation icon? I set the icon with the following code

```
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.locations_icon);
```

but i can't set the description text here

Comment: Not sure I understand the question but I think you will want to add a `textview` for the text and then call `textview.settext()` in your code. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452269/android-set-text-to-textview

Comment: @Drdavidpier refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490126/appcompat-style-background-propagated-to-the-image-within-the-toolbar step 2. There is the hint i am talking about

Comment: It would have to be done in your code, I believe. I don't think there's any XML attribute you can set for it. Is that acceptable?

Comment: Here is an example of showing a toast message under a view in the ActionBar/Toolbar: https://github.com/Mirkoddd/TabBarView/blob/master/TabBarViewLibrary/src/com/mirko/tbv/CheatSheet.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways I've used to get a `Toolbar`'s Navigation Button View. The first uses reflection on the `Toolbar` class, and the second iterates over a `Toolbar`'s child `View`s until it finds an `ImageButton`.

The reflective method:

```
private View getNavButtonView(Toolbar toolbar) {
    try {
        Class<?> toolbarClass = Toolbar.class;
        Field navButtonField = toolbarClass.getDeclaredField("mNavButtonView");
        navButtonField.setAccessible(true);
        View navButtonView = (View) navButtonField.get(toolbar);

        return navButtonView;
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

And the iterative method:

```
private View getNavButtonView(Toolbar toolbar) {
    for (int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++)
        if (toolbar.getChildAt(i) instanceof ImageButton)
            return toolbar.getChildAt(i);

    return null;
}
```

Please note that if you use the iterative method, it should be called immediately after setting the Navigation Icon, which should be called before any other `View`s are added or set on the `Toolbar`.

After we've gotten the `View`, we just need to set an `OnLongClickListener` on it, and show the `Toast` with an appropriate offset. For example:

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
View navButtonView = getNavButtonView(toolbar);

if (navButtonView != null) {
    navButtonView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),
                                             "Navigation Button View",
                                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                int[] loc = new int[2];
                v.getLocationOnScreen(loc);

                toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT,
                                 loc[0] + v.getWidth() / 2,
                                 loc[1] + v.getHeight() / 2);
                toast.show();

                return true;
            }
        }
    );
}
```