# Text background issue on Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

When adding some alpha to my Toolbar background color, I notice there is a background applied to the title's TextView:

[image: Toolbar title background]

**Here is my layout:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:background="#0099cc">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ActionBarTitle"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/image"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**And my styles.xml:**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>

        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <!--For compatibility-->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@color/black_overlay</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTitle" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
        <item name="android:textSize">50sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

"black_overlay" color value is `#66000000`

I am using AppCompat and Support libraries `v24.2.1`.

Do you have any idea on how to get rid of this text background?

Cheers.

Answer (score 11):

As you can see in the following [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490126/appcompat-style-background-propagated-to-the-image-within-the-toolbar), the problem comes from the attribute `app:theme`. It is applied to every view that a viewgroup inflate.
Replace `app:theme` by `style`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    style="@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ActionBarTitle"/>
```

Comment: perfect, and the cool thing is that you can use the `app:theme` at the same time and set all the properties you want except for the background keep it in `style`

Answer (score 0):

Alright, removing the background properties on the FullscreenActionBarStyle style and putting it in the Toolbar layout definition make it work.
As @apelsoczi pointed out, settings these properties in the toolbar style also apply them on children components.

Answer (score -1):

Encapsulate a TextView inside the Toolbar and set the value of that.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        ...>
        <TextView ... />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Well, it's a hacky workaround, and not the best solution :D

Comment: If this works for you - please select the answer as the chosen solution to officially close the question on StackOverflow. A bit of insight as to why this happens: keep in mind the Toolbar is a ViewGroup with multiple child layouts and other Views, the properties which you change for the ViewGroup will always be inherited by the children.